# VBA Get data from Web with date in the link

Tags: excel, vba

I am at the very beginning of trying to learn about web scraping and I have so far done this:

```
Sub BrowseStatsLAN()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument


XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/ftu?startDate=2019-09-05&endDate=2019-12-05&matchType=Lan&rankingFilter=Top100", False
XMLPage.send

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

End Sub

Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Set mySh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet15")
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer


    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables

        Range("A3").Value = HTMLTable.className
        Range("B3").Value = Now

        RowNum = 4
        For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            'Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innerText

            ColNum = 1
            For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
                Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Next HTMLCell

            RowNum = RowNum + 1
        Next HTMLRow

    LastTableColumn = LastColumn

        Next HTMLTable

End Sub
```

Now I am able to get the table that I want but the link includes startDate and endDate which I would like to update automatically. For example, that I get the most recent date and -30 days. So my question is, is there a way to automatically refresh this part of URL? I would like to type start and end date in my worksheet above the table.

Answer (score 0):

The url is a simple string. So you can use concatination to connect the fix parts with the calender dates in variables:

```
Sub BrowseStatsLAN()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim startDate As String
Dim endDate As String
Dim url As String

startDate = Sheets("sheet name").Cells(Row, Column) 'Your refererence to the start date in your excel table
startDate = Sheets("sheet name").Cells(Row, Column) 'Your refererence to the end date in your excel table

url = "https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/ftu?startDate=" & startDate & "&endDate=" & endDate & "&matchType=Lan&rankingFilter=Top100"

XMLPage.Open "GET", url, False
XMLPage.send

'here the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help! It is working now.